# How to keep footer on the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have tried everything but footer is not at the bottom of page. 
I tried `position: fixed;` but always when I scroll down it stays on the same position.

```
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -142px;
}

.footer, .push {
  height: 142px;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: try this  .footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:black;
}

Comment: Are you talking about sticky footer or the footer that should be at the bottom of the page?

Comment: right at the bottom of the page. I tried position: fixed;
                                                            bottom: 0;

Answer (score 0):

Use following CSS:

```
.footer { 
  position:fixed; 
  left:0px; 
  bottom:0px; 
  height:142px; 
  width:100%; 
 background:black; 
}
```

here is test fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/85nyb2mv/

Answer (score 0):

If to use `position: fixed`, the element will always be at the same position of the screen. If you want footer to be at the bottom of wrapper element, try to give `position: relative` to `.wrapper` and `position: absolute` to `.footer`, it will place your footer at the bottom of wrapper. Here is an example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -142px;
background-color: gray;
position: relative;
}

.footer, .push {
 height: 142px;
 width: 100%;
 background: black;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="footer"></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS styles:

```
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100% - 142px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  height: 142px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CASE 1**

When `body`' `height` is bigger than `100vh`

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}
header{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
}
footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background:darkgray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

**CASE 2**

When `body`' `height` is smaller than `100vh`

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}
header{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
}
footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background:darkgray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**html**
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <section>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

**CSS**
<style type="text/css">
 footer { 
  position:fixed; 
  left:0px; 
  bottom:0px; 
  width:100%; 
  background:black; 
  color:#fff;
  z-index:99;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `<div class="fade">`, so I removed it and added

```
.page-content:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

`<div class="page-content">` ----> between header and footer